# Clearing a session

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a session class where i am saving text box values(application) in a session. However, when the user times out due to inactivity or just goes back to the home page i want to clear all session data.
    I tried to set it in the  homepage but the !IsPostBack keeps firing.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    JobPositionSystemDAL jps = new JobPositionSystemDAL();
    DataSet ds = jps.GetJobs();

    GridView2.DataSource = ds;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}

if (IsPostBack)
{
    Session.RemoveAll();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I cant accept answers im not happy with can i?

Comment: If you have asked 92 questions and only received "acceptable" answers for 50 of them, you should work on clarifying your questions, or maybe offering bounties on them.  I find it very difficult to believe that you've asked 42 questions that are so challenging or on such obscure (yet relevant) topics that no one on SO can answer them.  http://www.xkcd.com/1028/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The session will automatically clear when it timesout (due to user inactivity, as you put it).

If you want to clear the session whenever the user in on the homepage, just do that. No need to keep checking if it is a postback or not.

When going *directly* to the homepage (say through a link on another page), `IsPostBack` is `false` - this is why `!IsPostBack` is `true` and the code within that `if` block executes.